# Windows Phone 8 control, like in Photos app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, controls

What control is used in native Photos app? I need the same experience, can I achieve it with Pivot or Panorama? Maybe its just a rotated LongListSelector?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking about how the single photo viewer feature of the Photos app is implemented, right? If so, check out the Media Viewer control that is part of this sample Lens app here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Lens-sample-359fda1b

Answer (score 0):

They use a [Panorama control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941104%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), not a Pivot or LongListSelector. At least not for the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: But how do they avoid item overlapping? I've found no easy way to do it.

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you mean? But if you add content in separate PanoramaItems it should not be an issue.

Comment: Standard panorama shows the 10px preview of the next item on the right side. The control in the Photos app - doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a control for that... [found here](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/12-11-13/radslideview-for-windows-phone-one-step-closer-to-the-native-photo-browsing-experience.aspx)
Not sure how to implement that on with the basic controls though